# Not able to make second request in the Apache HttpAsyncClient callback

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I try to make a second request in the HttpAsyncClient callback. But the second request is on wait state.

Example code:

```
package com.example.http;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class AsyncClientHttpExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
        httpClient.start();

        final HttpGet request1 = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/ip");

        httpClient.execute(request1, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse result) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity()));

                    final HttpGet anotherRequest = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/headers");

                    Future<HttpResponse> future1 = httpClient.execute(anotherRequest, null);
                    HttpResponse anotherResponse = future1.get(); //the code get hand up here.

                    System.out.println("response 1 " + anotherResponse);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I don't quite understand why the second request got hand up in the `anotherResponse`. I thought the second request is waiting for some lock that has already captured by request 1. But I haven't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, we also ran into the same problem and while I don't yet know how things are implemented internally, I have a fair handle on why the code hangs.

I found that internally, there are multiple workers, each with their own queue to process certain events like connection establishment, session creation, etc. When the worker finds some element in the queue, the event is processed in the same thread that polls the queue. This includes execution of the user-level callback function.

I observed that all the requests I created to the same route would always get added to the same worker's queue. This leads to a deadlock now because:

1. The callback function is waiting for the new request to complete
2. The new request is waiting in the queue to be picked up for processing
3. The thread that polls the queue is waiting for the callback to complete

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use blocking `Future#get` inside a callback!!! This basically blocks not only the callback itself but also all other I/O sessions associated with the same I/O reactor thread.

Refactor your code to process the result of the operation from a `FutureCallback`.